# Prove the following successive differential

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

> Let $f(x)$ be a function such that
>
> $f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{a^2-x^2}$, then use the identity
>   $\displaystyle
>  \frac{1}{a^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{a+x}+\frac{1}{a-x}\right)$
>   to prove that
>
> $f^n(x) = \displaystyle\frac{n!}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{(a-x)^{n+1}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{(a+x)^{n+1}}\right)$

Now, given that I'm not very familiar with successive differentiation, I don't know of any rules or formulas that can aid in this case, hence I've resolved to merely using inspection, so far of only up to the $3^{rd}$ derivative. I also know that ideally, each derivative should have the same number of terms. This is not an issue in this case though, as the question layout ensures this.

So, lets look at the first $3$ derivatives:

$\displaystyle y_1=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{-1}{(a+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(a-x)^2}\right)$

$\displaystyle y_2=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{2}{(a+x)^3}+\frac{2}{(a-x)^3}\right)$

$\displaystyle y_3=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{-6}{(a+x)^4}+\frac{6}{(a-x)^4}\right)$

Immediately, there's a lot of information to inspect, and the first formula that comes to mind is:

$\displaystyle y_n=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(a+x)^{n+1}}+\frac{n!}{(a-x)^{n+1}}\right)$

and from here, naturally you rearrange to present the equation in the form it is needed in, by factoring out $n!$ and swapping the terms inside the parenthesis. So:

$\displaystyle y_n=\frac{n!}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{(a-x)^{n+1}}+\frac{(-1)^n}{(a+x)^{n+1}}\right)$

The question on the table is that you read the proof I've provided and confirm whether or not it is valid (keeping in mind that I do not know how to, or if its possible to prove the formula for $f^n(x)$ rigorously, where $f(x)$ is any function.)

Thank you, any responses are appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Use induction to prove that, $$\left(\frac{1}{ax+b}\right)^{(n)}=a^n\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(ax+b)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Use induction if it is true for n then ot is true for (n+1)

Comment: What you have written is what you would do in order to discover the formula.  But the formula is already give to you, so you do not need to to that.  Instead (as noted by the others) you would do a proof by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already showed that the formula is valid for $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$. Assume that is valid for $$y_{n-1}=\frac{(n-1)!}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{(a-x)^n}+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(a+x)^n}\right)$$ If you just take the derivative you get $y_n$. This is called proof by induction.

Comment: Actually I was aware of proof by induction, but I was not sure whether or not the use of proof by induction is appropriate in this context. Can you perhaps point out why proof by induction is acceptable in this case?

Comment: Any time you have a problem that involves a recurrence relationship, proof by induction seems like a logical choice. In this case you need to know the derivative of order $n-1$ in order to calculate the derivative of order $n$

Comment: I know that proof by induction requires proof for $n=1$ and then you assume it's true for $n=k$ and then prove its true for $n=k+1$, so why do I need to prove the derivative of order $n=k-1$ instead of $n=k+1$? Or does it not matter?

Comment: It does not matter. It its just that if you know one iteration you can go to the next one

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!